# poor resolution satellite images

Tags: image, resolution, satellite

When using the static map API, I get poor resolution images, compared to what I see in Google maps.  The URL I use (which I used before and obtained good images) is the following:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=32.932928,-117.204587&zoom=21&sensor=false&size=640x640&maptype=satellite&format=png32

Any idea?

Comment: You don't give much detail to help someone provide an answer. What have you tried? What was the result? Can you provide a side-by-side comparison?

Comment: Seems that the image I obtain is older, and of poorer quality.  this is the image I obtain:

Comment: The URL I included is used to download a 640x640, zoom 21 image (you can just put it in the browser).  If you look for the same area in google maps (just put 32.932928,-117.204587 in the search window), you can see a completely different, much better, image.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am facing the same problem right now :/